# Thingworx output JSON error if output populate with push

Tags: json, output, thingworx

I have an object to response but It has an array to add multiple object into this inside array, you can see in below. The problem is if this inside array populate with push or something else `Thingworx` is stop running.

*Response structure:*

```
var last = {
    plans: []
};
```

*Populating this object:*

```
last.plans[0] = Inputs.offers[1]; 
OR
last.plans.push(Inputs.offers[1]);
```

If I want to return `last` `Thingworx` is stop working.

But if return like this;

```
var result = Inputs.offers[1];
```

It's return well. What if more than 1 result in it. I used `push` into array that reason.

By the way, output type is `JSON`.

Answer (score 0):

Strange should work, when you mean return last, you mean:

```
var result = last;
```

And when you say "stop working" what does you mean? which error message do you get?

Comment: Actually I didn't get any error. It's stacked on tomcat side I think. Because thingworx ask me login credentials after wait some time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Find a solution at the end. Fixed. This is the final code block.

```
var last = {
    plans: []
};
var offer = JSON.parse(offers[0]);
last.plans.push(offer);
```

`JSON.parse`is my solution. `offers[0]` is already json object. I'm not sure why `thingworx` needs to parse this structor.